How to override a component which is referred in outlet. Example, How to override CartItemListComponent which is used as outlet
We want to define new design for cart cart entries in checkout and order page. For this we want to override CartItemListComponent shipped OOTB of spartacus. How can we do that?
I tried overriding this configuration and both the components have appeared now. Tried replace as well, both the components are appearing.

You can only override a CMS components.
For your scenario ,define a new custom component& in providerOutlet configuration define your component.
Then your component should be picked.


    provideOutlet({
      id: CartOutlets.CART_ITEM_LIST,
      component: CustomComponent,
      position:OutletPosition.REPLACE
      
    }),



